# Pull to Refresh on ViewPager

Tags: android

I'm looking to implement pull to refresh on a ViewPager, and I'm curious what the best way to go about it is.

It looks like just setting a page transformation on the ViewPager wouldn't really do the trick, as you really want things like onAbsorb, which is available in EdgeEffect.

Just implementing an EdgeEffect doesn't seem like the right choice, since AFAICT, it won't move any of the existing children around.

I'd rather not use the PullToRefresh library (since it isn't being maintained), and would prefer to do mostly custom stuff -

Any advice on what approach is the most promising way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to implement the pull to refresh by yourself, there are several good 3rd party libraries which are very easy to use.

But pull to refresh maybe not a good choice on android, a refresh action button is better.

[A widely used pulltorefresh library.](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)

Comment: Did you read in the original question that I didn't particularly want to use this? Do you have some reason to think that an abandoned library is a good choice here?

Comment: Yes i read your question, and my opinion is that just use the PullToRefresh library, even it is not maintain any more. This library is small, compact, approx bug free and used in many apps. The idea of the library to solve pull to refresh is really brilliant. Even you don't want to use it, you can still read the source code and consider a better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It is slide to refresh that you want, as it is ViewPager. Detect a swipe (left on first element and right on last) and request for new data, when the detection is positive. For that you want onInterceptTouch over a Custom ViewPager, and a SwipeGesture detector. After that you can try other custom features that you suggest in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to implement pull to refresh on a ViewPager, and I'm
>   curious what the best way to go about it is.

You sited you didn't want to use the PullToRefresh library, and I get that. But I would start your research/exploration there if you are looking for similar behavior. Chris' repos have a healthy commit history, and from those you can infer some decisions regarding design choices, pitfalls, and fixes.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

With something like a scroll view, I imagine you can have EdgeEffects and PTR in the actionbar and not worry about moving children at all (with it working right out of the box - His google play sample app has that behavior). But I'm not sure if that is the exact effect you are looking for.

Answer (score -8):

Don't implement pull to refresh on Android. I know it's not the answer, but pull to refresh is an iOS convention, not an Android one.

Comment: What about apps  like Gmail?